# How do I change speedometer caption style changes in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

[image]

I want to customize the hover effect to depict values with different bullet colors (basically like a customized html snippet).How do I achieve this? Which parameter I'm supposed to add while initiating object in highcharts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which library you are using ?

Comment: You just want to change the color of bullets and not the speedometer? I mean the gradient on it's perimeter?

Comment: @MayP Try using lightweight jq plugin  https://github.com/rmanivannan/speedometer-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the format of the tooltip via the pointFormat property of the tooltip. Check out this [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2oyjtduv/2/)

```
tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> You can change the tooltip format here: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
        valueSuffix: ' km/h'
    }
```

See the other properties of the tooltip [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip);

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) which allows to customise tooltip content according to your request.

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
        }
    },
```